# how to auto lunch apk in mobile without tapping on app icon in kotlin programmetically?

Tags: android

I am trying lunch application background. I destroyed the APK but thorough background task, I want to
lunch . I tried using broadcast and service nothing worked not able to lunch APK. like alarm   activity when time comes it will automatically open the APK.

Comment: An alarm clock app does not automatically "open the APK". An alarm clock app uses a high-priority notification with a full-screen `Intent`, such that the OS will start an activity using that `Intent` *in safe circumstances*. With regards to "nothing worked", [starting activities from the background is restricted](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts), for security and safety reasons.